# DataBinding to Charts

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, .net-4.0, data-visualization

I am trying to create some charts for a C# .NET 4.0 Winforms application. I have begun with the pie-Chart. Is there a way to use databinding in order to keep the chart updated?

So far I have only managed to use the `DataPoint.YValues` property to change the chart's appearance.

The `Series` object has got a `DataSource` property, but I am not sure how to use this `DataSource` for the single points (which are inside a list, inside the series property).

I hope I could explain my question detailed enough.

PS: The charts are from the `System.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` namespace.